# Inputs in different threads, that don't interrupt each other

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Nothing really serious, just a simple Python example:

```
import threading


def t1():

    print(f'in thread2 %s\n' % input("\n t1 "))

def t2():

    print('in thread1 %s \n' % input("\n t2 "))



def main():

    t_2 = threading.Thread(target=t1)
    t_2.daemon = True
    t_2.start()

    t_1 = threading.Thread(target=t2)
    t_1.daemon = True
    t_1.start()


main()
```

And now it's output

```
>>> 
 t1                               # this line was skipped, and it moved on to t2
 t2 data2                         # then i entered value for t2
data1                             # and only then it asked for t1
in thread2 data2
in thread1 data1
```

I understand why is it processing in such a way. I can't just get two lines of input simultaneously using multithreaded architecture.

---

**QUESTION**: 
*How can i get two inputs simultaneously that don't interrupt each other?*

---

Note, that i prefer not to open two separate console windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the python version?

Comment: It's Python 3.7